# work with different files in c++

Tags: c++, oop

Hello I have a simple program with a `main.cpp` an `a.h` and an `a.cpp`. I'd like to define a class in a.cpp and simply call on the method of the class in `main.cpp`

my `a.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Hello 
{
 string hello();
};
```

my a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>

string class Hello::hello(){return "hello world";};
```

my main.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

 int main()
 {
  Hello h;
  cout << h.hello();


 }
```

EDIT : changed the `include"a.cpp"` to `a.h` and added the string to the definition of the method hello. added the `#include <string>` to a.h

while compiling I get the error

"a.cpp:4:22: error: ‘hello’ in ‘class Hello’ does not name a type
  string class Hello::hello() {return "Hello";};"

"a.cpp:4:28: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
  string class Hello::hello() {return "Hello";};"

Comment: Make it `string Hello::hello(){return "hello world";}` You also need `#include <string>` in the header.

Comment: Never put `using namespace ` into global scope in the header. It will affect all the files, which include the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple problem, you have declared a function as part of your class:

```
class Hello {
// ^Function is part of the class Hello.

string hello();
// ^Function returns a string
//      ^Function is called "hello"
//           ^Function takes no arguments.
```

So when you go to define the function you need to give the compiler the same information:

```
string Hello::hello() {
// ^Function returns a string
//      ^Function is part of the class Hello
//             ^Function is called "hello"
//                  ^Function takes no arguments.
```

- You will also need to add the header `<string>` to your file to facilitate the use of the `string` object.
- Your `'#include "a.cpp"` needs to be `#include "a.h"`, a rule of thumb is you should never ever see `#include file.c/cpp`.
- Finally, you will need to make the function `hello` public to allow its use outside class members.

[Here is a live example for you to play with.](http://ideone.com/JJLUac)

But the best advice i can give, is pick up a c++ beginners book. It will do you a world of good. [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: i tried this solution but i keep getting the error :
a.cpp:4:22: error: ‘hello’ in ‘class Hello’ does not name a type
  string class Hello::hello() {return "Hello";};
                      ^
a.cpp:4:28: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
  string class Hello::hello() {return "Hello";};

during compilation i use g++ to compile

Comment: Read my answer again. You have not invested the time to read it properly. Have a look at the live example.

Comment: Solved thank you very much, sorry for not seeing it now its so clear

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hello::hello(){return "hello world";};   // Replace it 
      // with
string Hello::hello(){return "hello world";};  // hello() has string return-type
```

Also, add `string` header-file into your file